# Update rails videojs version cause runtime error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I recently update rails video.js version 5.10.7 (was previously using a 4.12.15 version), and videojs-contrib-media-sources version 3.1.2 (was previously using a 1.0.0 version)according to [these](https://rails-assets.org), instructions and noticed that I now consistently get the following errors.
[runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqIRr.png)